# Can I see when my/a Flair was/will be updated?

Tags: support, flair, combined-flair

> (please note that only sites where you have more than 200 reputation will appear, and that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours.)

Can I see when the last update was, or, even better, what the -estimated- time of the next update is?

Comment: Time estimate: 12-18h statistically.